# Why are people using min/max function in SAS with only one argument

Tags: sas

In SAS, the min/max function can take only one input argument.  E.g.
`min(42)`

My question is why would people want to use these functions with only one input argument?  What is it compared to (when there is only one input)?

Comment: Can you show example code?  Is this in the data step or in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using a variable list whose size is not known in advance.  So it is useful if the function handles lists of only one value.  For example if you want to MIN() of all variables with names that start with COST you could code:

```
min_cost = min(of cost:);
```

Or you might be generating the list of values via macro logic or other code generation techniques.

```
proc sql noprint; select cost into :costs separated by ',' from have; quit;
data want;
  min_cost = min(&costs);
run;
```

Note it still requires at least one argument, but you can code around that by providing it an extra missing value.

```
min_cost=min(., of cost:);
```

And finally if they are using PROC SQL then they are actually calling a different function.  The SQL aggregate function.  That function only allows one argument but it aggregates the value over multiple observations.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select product, min(cost) as min_cost 
    from have
    group by product
  ;
quit;
```